# Average_ttl is 0 on one of the Redis cluster nodes

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I have a Drupal cluster of 3 servers that are using HAproxy (TCP) to handle communication with a Redis cluster of 3 nodes (used for caching) on which the sentinel service is active as well.

The Redis cluster has 1 main (master) node and 2 secondary (slave) nodes in replication mode.

I recently noticed that the avg_ttl is zero on one of the secondary (slave) nodes.

It's weird, I mean the data is synced between these nodes so they should have the same keys.

I checked the configuration and they almost have the same configuration in the *redis.conf* file.

Any idea what could this mean?

Thanks!

[avg_ttl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlSXu.png)

[Replication Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccb19.png)